# C++: how to define a class method as a start routine to thread (with pthread library)

Tags: c++, pthreads, function-pointers

i have a **Base** class and **Derived** class.
they have a virtual function- **virtual void action()**
how can i pass it to *pthread_create()* function?

example(with errors):

```
class Base{
  protected:
     pthread_t tid;
  public:
  virtual void* action() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base{
  void* action();
  Derived(){
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &action, NULL);
  } 
};
```

maybe it should be static?
i tried lot of combinations but cant find solution..

Comment: Maybe you should use `boost::thread` or `std::thread` (of c++11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem a couple months back working on my senior design project. It requires some knowledge of underlying C++ mechanics.

The underlying issue is that pointers to functions are different from pointers to member functions. This is because member functions have an implicit first parameter, `this`.

From the `man` page:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread,
                   const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *),
                   void *arg);
```

The thread entrance point is a `void* (*)(void*)`. Your function, `Base::action` has the type `void* (Base::*)()`. The `Base::` part of that ugly type declaration denotes the type of `this`. The type discrepancy is why the compiler won't accept your code.

There's two things we need to fix to make this work. We can't use a member function, because pointers to member functions don't bind `this` to an instance. We also need a single parameter of type `void*`. Thankfully, these two fixes go hand in hand because the solution is to explicitly pass `this` ourselves.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void* action() = 0;

protected:
    pthread_t tid;

    friend void* do_action(void* arg) {
        return static_cast<Base*>(arg)->action();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        // This should be moved out of the constructor because this
        // may (will?) be accessed before the constructor has finished.
        // Because action is virtual, you can move this to a new member
        // function of Base. This also means tid can be private.
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &do_action, this);
    }

    virtual void* action();
};
```

**Edit:** Woops, if `tid` is `protected` or `private`, then `do_action` needs to be a `friend`.

Comment: How do we pass Pointer to Action function. If so is required?
void* func(void* p)

Answer (score 3):

You have to have a function that takes one void pointer to pass to `pthread_create`. I'd write the function myself, as a function that takes a pointer to `Base` (`Derived` would work as well), then call the `action` function of the parameter. You can then create a thread that runs the function and received `this` as parameter:

```
void *f(void *param)
{
    Base* b = (Base *)param;
    return b->action();
}

class Derived : public Base{
  void* action();
  Derived() {
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, f, this);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it has to be static. You'll also need to pass your object as an argument to pthread_create:

```
void *Base::static_action(void *v)
{
    ((Base*)v)->action();
    return NULL;
}

pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &Base::static_action, myObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something similar to this, I'll let you fill in the other details (error handling, locking, etc):

Start method:

```
bool pthreadBase::start()
{
   return pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, &execute,this);
}
```

Static void* Execute method:

```
void *pthreadBase::execute(void *t)
{
   reinterpret_cast<pthreadBase *> (t)->processLoop();
   return NULL;
}
```

After, you can just make a virtual method called processLoop that will act as an entry point for your thread.

Here's a simple implementation (NOT TESTED):

```
class theThread: public pthreadBase
{
   public:
      theThread(SharedMemoryStructure *SharedMemory)
      {
         _Running = start();
         _Shared = SharedMemory;
      }

      ~theThread()
      {
         stop(); //Just do a join or something
         _Running = false;
      }

   private:
      void processLoop()
      {
         while(_Shared->someQuitFlag() == false)
         {
            /*Do Work*/
         }
      }

   private:
      bool _Running;
      SharedmemoryStructure *_Shared;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Making it static isn't really guaranteed to work, but actually does at least with most implementations (and enough people depend on it that I'd be a little surprised to see that change soon either).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why "static" is not guaranteed to work?

Comment: @Arkadiy: Simply put, because there's nothing to say it is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Jerry Could you elaborate further, as in what you'd expect to see that would give you assurance it would work? There isn't anything that says a threading library written and compiled in C is guaranteed to work at all, and yet it does.

Comment: @SanJacinto: What I'd want to see would be a statement in the C++ standard that other than the name qualification, a static member function is equivalent to a non-member function, so pointers to both have the same type.

Comment: This is sidestepping the issue. Why make it a static? Just make it a global, and the semantics are well defined.