# How to make a method call another method in the same class in a new thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, pthreads

I need to make a method in a class call another method in the same class in a new thread but am having some trouble. I get the compile error: " 'this' is unavailable for static member functions". I made an example of my issue since I can't post the raw code here.

Basically, what happens is I make an object of my class (known as `aClass` in the below example) then I call a method such as `do_stuff()`. The `do_stuff()` method uses `pthread_create` to call the `print_number()` method in a new thread. The problem is, when I go to compile I get an error saying that I can't use `this` because my `print_number()` method is static. If I don't make the `print_number()` method static, then `pthread_create` complains that its not a compatible type.

I understand why I wouldn't be able to use `this` inside the `print_number()` method itself since it's static and can then be called with no object. However, in my `print_number()` method, I'm not using `this`. I'm using the pointer to the object I created. In `do_stuff()` I use `this` to pass a reference to the object I created to `print_number` but I don't use `this` in `print_number` itself. So I'm not understanding what the issue is. Thanks for the help!

```
class aClass 
{
    private:
    number;

    public:
    void do_stuff(void);
    static void* print_number(void* arg)    

}

// this method is called first
void aClass::do_stuff()
{
    number = 4;
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_number, this);
    .....
}

//this method is called from the do_stuff() method in a new thread
void* aClass::print_number(void* arg)
{
    aClass* objPTR = (aClass*)arg;
    printf("number = %d", objPTR->number);
}

//don't get caught up here.. the point is that an object is created and
// the "do_stuff()" method is called
int main()
{
    //all the usual stuff here
    aClass someObject;
    someObject.do_stuff();
}
```

Comment: Look for "pthread_create class method". This one, for example, can shed more light on the problem: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809987/c-how-to-define-a-class-method-as-a-start-routine-to-thread-with-pthread-lib)

Answer (score 0):

U need to make the print_number declaration static inside the class.
Just replace the line

```
class aClass 
{
    private:
    number;

    public:
    void do_stuff(void);
    void* print_number(void* arg)   

};
```

with the below code

```
class aClass 
{
    private:
    int number;

    public:
    void do_stuff(void);
    static void* print_number(void* arg);

};
```

This is just the class part only.
Compile it hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, in the real code I do have static written in the class part. I just forgot to write it in my example here. Sorry about that! -modified above example.