# No matching function call when passing member function of a class to pthread_cleanup_push()

Tags: c++

When I try to pass my function `cleanup_thread()` to `pthread_cleanup_push()`:

```
pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_thread, arg);
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘__pthread_cleanup_class::__pthread_cleanup_class(<unresolved overloaded function type>, void*&)’
```

I guess its because `void cleanup_thread(void *arg)` is a member function of my class and therefor has the `this` pointer as first argument. So the signature of the function cleanup_thread() does not match.
How can I tell `pthread_cleanup_push()` to use my member function `cleanup_thread()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to make the function a `static` member function, and pass the instance pointer as the argument.

Something like this:

```
struct data_struct
{
    some_class* instance;
    pthread_t   thread_id;
};

class some_class
{
public:
    ...

    static void cleanup_thread(void* arg)
    {
        data_struct* ptr = reinterpret_cast<data_struct*>(arg);
        ptr->instance->private_cleanup_thread();
        delete ptr;
    }

private:
    void private_cleanup_thread()
    {
        ...
    }
};

...

some_class* some_class_ptr = new some_class;

...

data_struct* data_ptr = new data_struct;
data_ptr->instance = some_class_ptr;
data_ptr->thread_id = some_thread_id;

pthread_cleanup_push(&some_class::cleanup_thread, data_ptr);
```

Comment: Thanks. See also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809987/c-how-to-define-a-class-method-as-a-start-routine-to-thread-with-pthread-lib

Comment: But the function `private_cleanup_thread()` needs the void pointer argument `void* arg`. That's the thread that needs to be cleaned up after.

Comment: @tzippy If you need more data to be sent to the handler, then you can use a structure, containing a pointer to the instance and all other data needed.

Comment: Actually I need just one argument. A void pointer that is then casted to a thread structure which contains open filedescriptors and threadID.

Comment: Actually I can't make it static because I am using a member of that class in the function.

Comment: @tzippy And that's what I'm solving by using a static proxy function. I've also updated the answer with how to pass more data to the function through the use of structures. The thing is, you can't use plain non-static member functions without an instance of the class.