# Multithreaded timer class

Tags: c++, pthreads, signals, ubuntu-14.04

I've created a timer class that performs a user supplied action (function that takes no arguments has no return type) at a user supplied interval. This action should be performed in its own thread--i.e. when the timer is created, a new thread is created, and that thread consists of a loop that uses `sigwait` to wait for the signal to come in before performing the callback.  The signal I want to use will be anywhere from `SIGRTMIN` to `SIGRTMAX`. I want to be able to create multiple timer objects which means multiple threads and multiple signals (one thread and signal per timer).  Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809987/c-how-to-define-a-class-method-as-a-start-routine-to-thread-with-pthread-lib), the `timer_create` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html), and `pthread_sigmask` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) as references, this is what I have:

```
//timer.h
#ifndef TIMERS_H
#define TIMERS_H
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

class CTimer
{
public:
    CTimer(uint64_t period_ms, void(*callback)(void), int sig );
private:
    typedef void (*Callback)(void);
    Callback m_pCallback;
    timer_t timerID;
    struct sigevent sev;
    struct itimerspec its;
    struct sigaction sa;
    uint8_t timerNum;

    pthread_t thread_id;
    sigset_t set;
    int signal_ID;
    void* loop();

    friend void* run_loop(void* arg);
};
#endif // TIMERS_H
```

and

```
//timer.cpp
#include "timers.h"

void* run_loop(void* arg)
{
    return static_cast<CTimer*>(arg)->loop();
}

CTimer::CTimer(uint64_t period_ms, void(*callback)(void), int sig):
               m_pCallback(callback), signal_ID(sig)
{
    //create mask to send appropriate signal to thread
    int s;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    s = sigaddset(&set, signal_ID);
    if (s != 0)
    {
        printf("error on sigaddset\n");
    }
    s = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
    {
        printf("error on pthread_sigmask\n");
    }
    //create new thread that will run the signal handler
    s = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, run_loop, this);
    if (s != 0)
    {
        printf("error on pthread_create\n");
    }

    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = signal_ID;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerID;
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timerID) == -1)
    {
        printf("error on timer create\n");
    }
    its.it_value.tv_sec = period_ms / 1000;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = period_ms % 1000;
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = its.it_value.tv_sec;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = its.it_value.tv_nsec;

    if (timer_settime(timerID, 0, &its, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("error on timer settime\n");
    }
}

void* CTimer::loop()
{
    int s = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        s = sigwait(&set, &signal_ID);
        m_pCallback();
    }
}
```

For testing I am using this:

```
//driver.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "sys/time.h"
#include "timers.h"

uint64_t get_time_usec()
{
    static struct timeval _time_stamp;
    gettimeofday(&_time_stamp, NULL);
    return _time_stamp.tv_sec*1000000 + _time_stamp.tv_usec;
}

void callbacktest1()
{
    printf("tick1 %" PRIu64 " \n", get_time_usec());
}

void callbacktest2()
{
    printf("tick2 %" PRIu64 " \n", get_time_usec());
}

int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
    CTimer t1(1000, callbacktest1, SIGRTMIN);
    CTimer t2(2000, callbacktest2, SIGRTMIN+1);

    pause();
}
```

When running, it will crash pretty quickly with the error "Real-time signal 1".  If I run it in gdb, I get

```
Starting program: /home/overlord/MySource/Timer/driver 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff75ee700 (LWP 21455)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff6ded700 (LWP 21456)]
tick1 1477336403700925 
tick1 1477336404700920 

Program received signal SIG35, Real-time event 35.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff75ee700 (LWP 21455)]
0x00007ffff7bcc0c1 in do_sigwait (sig=0x7fffffffdbc8, set=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/../../../../../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigwait.c:60
60      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/../../../../../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigwait.c: No such file or directory.
```

which is interesting because 35 is what SIGRTMIN+1 is equal to. So maybe I'm not routing the signals correctly? If I only create once instance of the timer in the driver.cpp file, things appear to work ok.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

I'm also curious if this is even the right approach to what I'm trying to do.  In some brief tests I did, using the system signals seems way more stable than using sleep and usleep to burn up unused loop time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the signal used to wake second thread (`CTimer t2`) is not blocked by the first thread (`CTimer t1`). Signal mask in a thread is inherited from a parent thread, so when you start first thread it only has `SIGRTMIN` signal blocked, but `SIGRTMIN+1` can still be delivered to it. Standard reaction to real-time signals is to terminate process, this is what happens. You can test this theory by blocking all real-time signals in all threads started by CTimer class.

I'm not sure why you think that sleep/usleep is less reliable than your own solution, using the right patterns with usleep (basically expecting that it can return sooner and waiting in a loop) always worked OK for me.

Comment: Yes this is correct.  It turns out that the `pthread_sigmask` sets the signals to be blocked for the entire process.  I had to move it out of the Timer class and set it by itself so that all possible timer signals would be blocked (i.e. SIGRTMIN to SIGRTMAX -- actually what I ended up doing was creating an additional class to manage all the timers and it gets set in there.  This isn't perfect since it could get overwritten outside the class--I believe there's a way to just append to the signals blocked, but I would need to look into it.)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure why you think that sleep/usleep is less reliable than
>   your own solution, using the right patterns with usleep (basically
>   expecting that it can return sooner and waiting in a loop) always
>   worked OK for me.

I did a basic test using the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>

#define CLOCKID CLOCK_REALTIME
#define SIG SIGRTMIN

#define SQ(x) ((x)*(x))

#define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
                       } while (0)

uint64_t start_time_us = 0;
double error_ms = 0;
int64_t count = 0;
int64_t last_time_us = 0;
uint64_t period_ns;

uint64_t get_time_usec()
{
    static struct timeval _time_stamp;
    gettimeofday(&_time_stamp, NULL);
    return _time_stamp.tv_sec*1000000 + _time_stamp.tv_usec;
}

static void
handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
   uint64_t timestamp_us = get_time_usec();
   double dt_ms = (double)(timestamp_us - last_time_us)/1000;
   double elapsed_ms = (double)(timestamp_us - start_time_us)/1000;
   error_ms += SQ((dt_ms - (double)period_ns/1000000.0));
   count++;
   last_time_us = timestamp_us;
}

namespace hidi
{
  void pause(const double& tSeconds)
  {
    unsigned int decimal = static_cast<unsigned int>(floor(tSeconds));
    double fraction = tSeconds-static_cast<double>(decimal);
    if (decimal > 0)
      sleep(decimal);
    usleep(static_cast<unsigned long>(floor(fraction*1000000.0)));
    return;
  }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   timer_t timerid;
   struct sigevent sev;
   struct itimerspec its;

   //sigset_t mask;
   struct sigaction sa;

   if (argc != 3) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <test length-secs> <period-millisec>\n",
               argv[0]);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   uint64_t period_ms = atoll(argv[2]);
   period_ns = period_ms * 1000000;

   /// FIRST TEST LOOP RATE STABILITY USING THE TIMER
   // THE TIMER WILL USE SIGRTMIN (DEFINED ABOVE) AND WILL MEASURE
   // STATISTICS ON LOOP STABILITY

   /* Establish handler for timer signal */

   printf("Establishing handler for signal %d\n", SIG);
   sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
   sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
   sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
   if (sigaction(SIG, &sa, NULL) == -1)
       errExit("sigaction");

   /* Create the timer */

   sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
   sev.sigev_signo = SIG;
   sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
   if (timer_create(CLOCKID, &sev, &timerid) == -1)
       errExit("timer_create");

   printf("timer ID is 0x%lx\n", (long) timerid);

   /* Start the timer */

   printf("Timing period is %zu ms\n", period_ms);
   its.it_value.tv_sec = period_ns / 1000000000;
   its.it_value.tv_nsec = period_ns % 1000000000;
   its.it_interval.tv_sec = its.it_value.tv_sec;
   its.it_interval.tv_nsec = its.it_value.tv_nsec;

   if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL) == -1)
        errExit("timer_settime");
   start_time_us = last_time_us = get_time_usec();

   printf("Sleeping for %d seconds\n", atoi(argv[1]));


   while ((get_time_usec()-start_time_us)/1000000 < atoi(argv[1]))
   {
    sleep(1); //this just prevents the while loop from spinning out of control
              // the sleep function is interrupted with the signal callback is
              // executed. All the magic happens in the callback.
   }
   printf("ave error: %8.6f ms %zu samples\n",sqrt((double)error_ms/(double)count), count);

   timer_delete(timerid); // disarm / delete timer


   /// START TEST USING SLEEP / USLEEP
   start_time_us = last_time_us = get_time_usec();
   error_ms = count = 0;

   while ((get_time_usec()-start_time_us)/1000000 < atoi(argv[1]))
   {
     uint64_t timestamp_us = get_time_usec();
     double dt_ms = (double)(timestamp_us - last_time_us)/1000;
     double elapsed_ms = (double)(timestamp_us - start_time_us)/1000;
     error_ms += SQ((dt_ms - (double)period_ns/1000000.0));
     //printf("et=%8.6f ms, dt=%8.6f ms ave error %f\n", elapsed_ms, dt_ms, error_ms/count);
     count++;
     last_time_us = timestamp_us;
     uint64_t consumed_time_us = get_time_usec()-timestamp_us;
     uint64_t remaining_looptime_us = (period_ns/1000) - consumed_time_us;
     hidi::pause((double)remaining_looptime_us/1000000.0);
    }

    printf("ave error: %8.6f ms %zu samples\n",sqrt((double)error_ms/(double)count), count);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

testing periods from 10 ms to 2 seconds, using timers just seemed way more stable.  It seemed using the sleep/usleep method the error was proportional to the period i.e. it was 2-3 ms for a 10 ms period, but 300 - 400 ms for a 1000 ms period. using the timer, the error was pretty constant with different periods.

Comment: Interesting. I was actually thinking about nanosleep() when I wrote about "right pattern", sorry for my sloppy wording. nanosleep() is supposed to be high-resolution, and the right pattern is to call it in a loop in case it gets interrupted by a signal.